# Swing: jLabel.setText invoked too late

Tags: java, swing

I have application with:

- one JTextField for user input,
- one JLabel fro showing busy status,
- one JTextArea for printing results of search.

I want user to write text to textfield, press enter and see results. I have listener like this:

```
private void searchForPattern(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        textArea.setText("");
        busyLabel.setText("Searchnig ...");
        doSearch();
        busyLabel.setText("Idle");
    }
```

In **doSearch** there is quite complicated algorithm that opens lots of XML files and searches for given pattern, it takes a while. Text of busyLabel is changed to Searching ... only after doSearch completed. There is no second thread in doSearch, only lot of IO operations.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a classic Swing concurrency issue (tutorial: [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)) where doSearch is tying up the Swing event thread.  Since this thread is where Swing does all of its painting/drawing and interacting with users, if it gets tied up by code that takes any perceptible amount of time to complete, the whole application "freezes" with no components getting updated and all user interactions getting ignored.

Solution: do it on a background thread such as that provided by a SwingWorker object. Set the "Idle" String into the JLabel in the SwingWorker's `done()` method.

i.e.,

```
private void searchForPattern(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  textArea.setText("");
  busyLabel.setText("Searching ...");
  new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        doSearch();
        return null;
     }

     @Override
     protected void done() {
        busyLabel.setText("Idle");
     }
  }.execute();
}
```

Comment: @Xorty: you're welcome. Be sure though to read the tutorial as it contains essential information if you're going to be doing any Swing coding.

Comment: Thanx, yeah I don't really plan to do Swing coding, but I'd definitelly read some documentation to understand how swing works if I had to use Swing more often.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  also the SwingUtilities's [invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method to to update the GUI swing components from an application thread.

```
private void searchForPattern(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
    new Runnable(){
      public void run(){        
         textArea.setText("");
         busyLabel.setText("Searchnig ...");
      }
    }
  );

  doSearch();

  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
    new Runnable(){
      public void run(){
         busyLabel.setText("Idle");
      }
    }
  );
}
```

**EDIT**
*PS*: here i assume that you have not called the searchForPattern() function from the EDT, that's mean if you call it from an ActionListener you have to called like this:

```
new Thread(
   new Runnable(){
      public void run(){
         searchForPattern(....)
      }
    }
  ).start();
```

Comment: This code above is probably not a good fit for the OP's current problem. There is a > 95% chance that the `searchForPattern(...)` method is being called on the EDT, and in fact looks to be called from a JButton's ActionListener given its ActionEvent parameter and the original poster's description of the problem. If so, then your suggestion will result in `doSearch()` being called on the EDT, which is exactly what shouldn't be done.

Comment: You have right i forget to mention that he have to call the `searchForPattern(...)` method in a new thread if he called it from an ActionListener.

Comment: Then perhaps you will want to edit your answer and show this thread. That would then make this a valid answer as that's pretty much what a SwingWorker does for you, but a SwingWorker has convenience methods such as publish and process that facilitate all of this.